# The meaning of random number generator test failing

Tags: pr.probability, algorithms, random-walks

I have a random number generator (number theoretic) that passes all of the [NIST tests](https://github.com/terrillmoore/NIST-Statistical-Test-Suite) *except* the random excursions test. Is there any deep dark meaning to this? To amplify "deep dark meaning", are there other number-theoretic sort-of-random function with the same property (as suggested by @LSpice in the comments)?

Comment: Why should this question have a better answer than the formally analogous question "I have a structure that satisfies the axioms of a group, except that multiplication is not associative.  Is there any deep dark meaning to this?"?

Comment: @LSpice The answer to your question might be: well, have you looked at the octonions? They are kind of interesting, and your structure might be related. There is lots of pseudo-randomness in number theory, and it may be that some other almost-random number-theoretic structure which fails the randomness test in the same way. This would be interesting to know. Snide comments, on the other hand, are of no interest except to yourself.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440314/the-meaning-of-random-number-generator-test-failing#comment1135714_440314), [it](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440314/the-meaning-of-random-number-generator-test-failing#comment1135711_440314) was not meant as a snide comment, although I can certainly see that my attempt at a joke as part of what I meant as a serious question fell flat; I apologise if I gave offence.  Your comment seems to me to make a better question:  "Are there other almost-random number-theoretic structures that fail the randomness test in the same way?"

Comment: @LSpice No offense taken, and yes, your version of the question is better.

Comment: It's possible that https://crypto.stackexchange.com/ would be a better site to ask this question.

Comment: @SamHopkins possibly, though I did not know it existed...

Comment: For more context, can you post description of or a link to the random number generator or pseudorandom number generator? Or can you post an example of a randomly generated sequence from that generator? I would like to run some tests on it.

Comment: And this post there may be helpful: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/71635/nist-random-excursion-results

Comment: Is your "random number generator" expressly designed to be such? Or is it a number-theoretic function that you happen to be studying and that you had no reason to expect to be structured, yet have discovered to fail the random excursions test? The reason I ask is that if it consistently fails the random excursions test then that is strong evidence of underlying structure, but what kind of structure it might be depends on whether the function arises "naturally" from some mathematical object that is interesting for other reasons, or whether it has been designed using cryptographic principles.

Comment: For example if you generate a sequence of binary digits and there are a lot more 1's than 0's, and your generator uses standard cryptographic routines, then chances are there's a bug in your code. On the other hand, if you're getting the digits from a [prime number race](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0408319), then the explanation will be completely different. NIST diagnostic tests are designed to detect non-randomness, not necessarily to be informative of exactly what type of structure is causing the non-randomness.

Comment: If we have a batch of 1's and 0's and run a compression algorithm on it, and it gets a lot smaller, then it necessarily has _some_ kind of structure (related to the compression algorithm). If it does not compress much (or gets larger...), then this indicates _some_ kind of "complexity" (as in Kolmogorof-Solomonoff-Chaitin), if not "randomness".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would fit better on crypto.stackexchange.

Comment: I was thinking about taking a string of bits produced by the random/pseudorandom number generator and then training a natural language processing model with it. If the NLP model learns anything, then the string of bits is probably not random/pseudorandom.